# issue while sharing a paticular div in fb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am working on a web application and i have added fb like button and share button. like button is woring fine but i have read the hyperarts tutorial from this SE question http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-share-button-iframe-tab-applications/ . but i have done the same procedure for sharing a particular div but i dono where i make a mistake . can anybody help me or can give suggestions. i have even fiddle it but does not work in my app . http://jsfiddle.net/EZyaF/

Here is the like code:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>    
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=425369200906567";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/weatherappproj" data-width="450"
    data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

and here is the Share a particular div code:

```
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script> 
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
      appId : '4x5x6x2x0x0x5x7',
   status : true, // check login status
       cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml : true // parse XFBML
      });
      };

      (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     e.async = true;
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
     }());
      </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">>
      $(document).load(function(){
    $('#shareonfb').live('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
     FB.ui(
     {
       method: 'feed',
        name: 'Weather App',
      picture: 'images/weatherapp.jpg',
     caption: 'My current position and its weather',
      description: 'Weather App Facebook',
     message: ''
    });
       });
     });
      </script>

    <img src="images/share-on-facebook-button.gif" id="shareonfb">
```

Comment: First of all, did you actually use `appId : '4x5x6x2x0x0x5x7'` or did you replace it for SO?

Comment: @asifrc: yes i have used it. thats app key, I am jus hiding it for security purpose. but still didnt work

Comment: You can not “share a DIV” on Facebook. Every Open Graph object is identified by its URL. So if you have specific content that you want to share, see to it that it is available under its own individual URL.